# End of file NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader, eof

What I wanted is to reach `EOF` by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> from command line with `BufferedReader` reading from console. The following code does so. But the problem is, it issues a `NullPointerException` after reaching `EOF`. Is there a way to skip this exception? Or more precisely, what is the proper way of reaching `EOF` with `BufferedReader` reading from console?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class EOF {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "";
        String EOF = "^z";
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            while (!s.equals(EOF)) {
                s = read.readLine();   
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {} 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Or more precisely, what is the proper way of reaching EOF with bufferedReader reading from console?

Currently you're actually detecting the characters '^' and 'z' it's not like '^' is really a control character.

The exception you're getting is actually a hint as to how you should be handling this. From the docs for [BufferedReader.readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):

> **Returns:**
>   A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

So basically you should loop until `readLine` returns `null`.

```
String line;
while((line = read.readLine()) != null)
{
    // Do something with line
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See how much a debugger can help:

[image]

After I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>, `s` has `null` value, hence you're getting this exception, since it's like writing `!null.equals(EOF)`.

**Why**?

Because [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) returns *"null if the end of the stream has been reached"*.

Answer (score 0):

Just use null as EOF signal.

```
    while((s=read.readLine())!= null)
    {
        .....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String str;
while((str=input.readLine()) != null ) {
    // 
}
```